# Join mysql table with distinct value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I encountered a problem on a database I am working with. I have a table of counsels which may hold repeating values, but their is an enrolment number filed which is unique and can be used to fetch them. However, I want to join from a cases_counsel table on the "first" unique value of the counsel table that matches that column on the cases counsel table.

I want to list the cases belonging to a particular counsel using the enrolment_number as the counsel_id on the cp_cases_counsel table. That means I want to pick just a distinct value of a counsel, then use it to join the cp_cases_counsel table and also return the count for such.
However, I keep getting duplicates. This was the mysql query I tried

```
SELECT T.suitno, T.counsel_id, COUNT(*) as total from cp_cases_counsel T
INNER JOIN (SELECT
    enrolment_number as id, MIN(counsel)
FROM
    cp_counsel
GROUP BY
    enrolment_number
) A
ON A.id = T.counsel_id
GROUP BY T.suitno, T.counsel_id
```

and

```
SELECT enrolment_number as id, MIN(counsel) as counsel, COUNT(*) as total FROM cp_counsel
JOIN cp_cases_counsel ON cp_cases_counsel.counsel_id = cp_counsel.enrolment_number
GROUP BY enrolment_number
```

For the second query, it's joining twice and I am having like double of what I am supposed to get.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please share more details. Is this even related to PHP? As you haven't shared any PHP code, I assume that you are searching for a pure MySQL solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns that you want in the results are `councel` (actually only one of all its values) from `cp_counsel` and `counsel_id` from `cp_cases_counsel`, so you must group by them and select them:

```
SELECT a.counsel, t.counsel_id, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM cp_cases_counsel t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT enrolment_number, MIN(counsel) AS counsel
  FROM cp_counsel
  GROUP BY enrolment_number
) a ON a.enrolment_number = t.counsel_id
GROUP BY a.counsel, t.counsel_id;
```